# How to get rid of input box on react-select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

**What I want**: A horizontal list of tabs at the top of my app with a little elipsis at the right end which, when clicked, displays a dropdown list display of the tabs. So if the tabs are 50 items long, the user can just click the dropdown. Clicking an item in the dropdown would have the equivalent behavior of clicking that tab.

**What I have that works**: Tabs are homebrewed and work fine. Elipsis displays the dropdown list fine (I am using [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home)) and the selection functionality all works.

**The problem:** When the user clicks the elipsis they see the selectable list of options, but between the elipsis and the selectable list is the menu input. ***I don't want that menu input and I want it gone completely from the screen.***

I tried fudging around with the [components api](https://react-select.com/components) for React-Select, but I don't even know where to start because there isn't any example code that I've found and I don't know how to decipher the documentation on the site.

What I got:

```
  <Select
    options={tabList}
    menuIsOpen={openMenu}
    defaultValue={blankOption}
    closeMenuOnSelect
    isSearchable={false}
    onChange={option => handleChange(option)}
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a code and example, so I suppose that you just want to remove an `input` that allows to search options in the `Select` component.
For this, you just need to add [`isSearchable`](https://react-select.com/props#select-props) prop with `false` value.

```
<Select
  isSearchable={false}
  ...
/>
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-5j2v4?from-embed)

Comment: I added `isSearchable={false}` but nothing changed.

Comment: @LCIII I have added an example

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I see that you've disabled the menu, but I want the menu to be gone completely--equivalent to `{display: none}` for it.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment when I said menu I meant to say *Input*. I still want the selectable list to display, but I want the input above it to disappear. So when a user clicks the elipsis they see only a selectable list appear without any input block.

Comment: @LCIII if you don't need a full `react-select` functionality, but just dropdown with options, it will be better to search for another library or write your own component. You are trying to import in your project big library with a lot of different functions and use one component that you could write quickly by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select
    options={options}
    styles={{
        container: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            display: 'inline-block',
        }),
        control: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            width: '40px',
        }),
        valueContainer: (base) => {
            return {
                ...base,
                display: 'none',
            }
        },
        menu: (base) => {
            return {
                ...base,
                width: '190px',
                right: 0
            }
        },
    }}
/>
```